# What does Stokes's Rule explain in regard to photons?

Tags: photons, photoelectric-effect

What process does it describe and does it break the Conservation of Energy? For more details, Stokes's Rule is mentioned in ***Einstein's Proposal of the Photon Concept***. [His dissertation about Stokes's Rule](https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/einstein/AJP_1905_photon.pdf)

Comment: It might help if you explained what Stoke's Rule is, as I can't find it with a cursory googling. Is it just another name for Stokes' Theorem?

Comment: Maybe it is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_shift). It doesn’t seem to be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law).